# PHP "list" question: Why the result is in reverse order?

Tags: php, arrays, list

Could you provide a detailed explanation to why this code:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
list($result[], $result[], $result[]) = $arr;
print_r($result);
```

results in:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 )
```

?

Comment: because that’s how `list()` works, cf. the php docs (http://php.net/list)

Comment: array_reverse() will solve all your problems!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the PHP docs for [`list`](http://php.net/list):

> list() assigns the values starting with the right-most parameter. If you are using plain variables,  you don't have to worry about this. But if you are using arrays with indices you usually expect the  order of the indices in the array the same you wrote in the list() from left to right; which it  isn't. It's assigned in the **reverse order**.

If you want to know *why* it does so, then the reason is probably, that a right-to-left assignment is easier to implement using a LALR(1) parser, where you normally use only left hand side recursion for performance reasons:

```
assignment_list:
      assignment_list ',' assignment_list_element
    | assignment_list_element
;

assignment_list_element:
      variable    { zend_do_add_list_element(&$1 TSRMLS_CC); }
    | T_LIST '('  { zend_do_new_list_begin(TSRMLS_C); } assignment_list ')' { zend_do_new_list_end(TSRMLS_C); }
    | /* empty */ { zend_do_add_list_element(NULL TSRMLS_CC); }
;
```

Comment: So the right most `$result[]` is set to `$arr[0]`. What happens then ?

Answer (score 3):

Because

> list() assigns the values starting with the right-most parameter. If you are using plain variables, you don't have to worry about this. But if you are using arrays with indices you usually expect the order of the indices in the array the same you wrote in the list() from left to right; which it isn't. It's assigned **in the reverse order**

So the actual answer is: that's how [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) works in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You have everything explain on this [LINK](http://si.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)...

It says:

> list() assigns the values starting with the right-most parameter. If you are using plain variables, you don't have to worry about this. But if you are using arrays with indices you usually expect the order of the indices in the array the same you wrote in the list() from left to right; which it isn't. It's assigned in the reverse order

Hope it helps!